# DataGridView shuffling column widths depending on visibility when control is added

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

[image: Demo of problem]

Both the 'Load' button on tabPage2 and the 'Load' Menu Item are running the same code, but as you can see in the demo above when the control is added when tabPage2 is not selected, the column widths shuffle despite it being the exact same code, the exact same control with the exact same content.

I'm not sure how relevant it is to the problem, but the UserControl I am adding looks like this:

[image: Added user Control]

Just a tab control with two tabs, a split container on the first tab with a DataGridView in the bottom split panel.

Each 'Load' creates a new tab page, a new user control, adds the user control to the tab page and then adds the tab page to the tab control on tabPage2.

Is there something at play here that I'm not aware of that would make controls render differently depending on their visibility when added?

EDIT: The DataGridView's are using DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill

Answer (score 1):

It does not have anything to do with the visibility of the tabs when adding the user control. To confirm you can keep the tabPage2 selected and you will see the same behavior as you currently have.

It is the selection and highlights of the tab controls that must be giving that notion. You can try adding around 4 user controls and click between tab2 and tab3 to confirm.

Comment: hi thanks for your comment - I have tested by keeping tabPage2 selected and loading with both the 'Load' button and the 'Load' Menu Item and it does not result in the shuffling. Also loading around 10 with a combination of both the button and the menu item does not result in the shuffling

Comment: @Tony: Can you try and print the column 1 width and compare the results and let me know.

Comment: When loading from the menu with tabPage1 selected: {141,142,142,142}        When loading from the button with tabPage2 selected: {142,142,141,142}

Comment: @Tony I assume these are auto widths.

Comment: I should have mentioned I am using DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill